# TinyMCE: show and hide inline toolbar on demand

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I use TinyMCE to edit content.
I initialize it in the following way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "div.editable",
    inline: true,
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
</script>
```

So, clicking divs with class 'editable' will show the TinyMCE inline editor.
I want **to show and hide it by clicking buttons, something like that**:

```
<input type="button" value="show inline editor for some div" onclick='tinymce.somediv.show()'>
```

I prepared a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vdRYL/15/) that shows the default behavior.

Please, help me find a way to show and hide the inline editor on demand for different divs.

Comment: You can use TinyMCE's "Load on demand". Take a look here: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/load_on_demand.php

Answer (score 1):

In tinymce, inline mode, I use simply:

```
tinymce.EditorManager.activeEditor.getElement().blur();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have already found an answer for your question. Since it was a bit hard for me to find exact answer, here's what I did at the end.

My TinyMCE Version 4.0.1

to show:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "div.editable",
    inline: true,
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
```

to hide (hide only inline editors):

```
$("#some_input_element").trigger("focus");// to remove focus from active editors
for (var i = tinymce.editors.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (tinymce.editors[i].inline)
        tinymce.editors[i].remove();
};
```

Removing editor while having focus gives unexpected results. So to be safe, I focus to a different input element before entering the for loop.